# Passing closure in swift as parameter to be used by selector in function

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a generic button creation function into which I pass a closure that represents the action that results as a result of clicking on the button. My code is below. However, I get the following error: 
 Argument of #selector cannot refer to property. Any suggestions for a workaround ? I don't want to write separate functions for which everything else is the same except for the target action.

```
 func myButton(textColor tColor:UIColor , title:String, 
                 _ buttonFcn: (UIButton) -> Void,   
                 titleSize:CGFloat=30) -> UIButton {
    let newButton = UIButton(type: .System)
    let bgColor = UIColor(red:204/255, green:204/255, blue:204/255, alpha:1.0)
    newButton.backgroundColor = bgColor

    newButton.setTitle(title, forState: .Normal)
    newButton.setTitleColor(tColor, forState: .Normal)

    newButton.titleLabel?.font = newButton.titleLabel?.font.fontWithSize(titleSize)


    newButton.addTarget(self,  action:#selector(buttonFcn),
                        forControlEvents: 
                           UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    return newButton
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I make #selector refer to a closure in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983633/can-i-make-selector-refer-to-a-closure-in-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the target-action mechanism is an Objective-C mechanism, and therefore is predicated on the notion that the action selector is a *method* of an *object*. You need, therefore, to have some NSObject-based *object* that has this function as a *method*, and which can then serve as the target.

Thus, if what differs in every case is the target and the action, what you need to pass is a reference to the target along with the selector *string*. Swift will squawk at this, but if you know how to form a selector string correctly you can certainly get away with it; you just won't be able to use the `#selector` syntax, and so you will risk crashing if you form the selector string incorrectly. But it's the kind of thing we used to do all the time in the old Objective-C days, so go right ahead if that's your aim.

Totally artificial but working example:

```
func buttonMaker(target:NSObject, selectorString:String) -> UIButton {
    let b = UIButton(type:.system)
    b.setTitle("Testing", for: .normal)
    b.addTarget(target, action: Selector(selectorString), for: .touchUpInside)
    b.sizeToFit()
    return b
}
```

And here's how to call it from a view controller:

```
func doButton(_ sender:Any) {
    print("ha!")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let b = buttonMaker(target:self, selectorString:"doButton:")
    b.frame.origin = CGPoint(x:100, y:100)
    self.view.addSubview(b)
}
```

And when we tap the button, we don't crash (rather, we print "ha"), because I know how to make selector strings correctly. But, as you can see, to accomplish this I had to give up the use of `#selector` altogether, so safety is out the window. If I had written my selector string incorrectly — for instance, if I had spelled it wrong, or omitted the colon — we'd have crashed on the button tap, just like we used to all the time before Swift `#selector` and Objective-C `@selector` were invented.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I ended up using a variation of your solution i.e. passing in a selectorString, but using the #selector syntax (to maintain compile-time checking) and a case statement to dispatch on the selectorString.

   ```func buttonMaker(selectorString:String, ..) -> UIButton {  
        switch selectorString {
        case "func1" :
            newButton.addTarget(self,  action:#selector(func1),
                                forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
       case func2:        
        }
        return newButton
    }```

Answer (score 0):

If your deployment target is iOS 14 or later, you can use the `addAction` method instead of `addTarget`. The `addAction` method lets you use a closure instead of a selector:

```
func myButton(
    textColor: UIColor,
    title: String,
    titleSize: CGFloat = 30,
    _ handler: @escaping (UIButton) -> Void
) -> UIButton {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 204/255, green: 204/255, blue: 204/255, alpha: 1.0)
    button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(textColor, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = button.titleLabel?.font.withSize(titleSize)

    let action = UIAction { action in
        guard let button = action.sender as? UIButton else { return }
        handler(button)
    }
    button.addAction(action, for: .touchUpInside)

    return button
}
```

iOS 14 was released on 2020-09-16 and supports iPhone 6S and later devices.