# How to call a block of code in #selector?

Tags: ios, swift, selector

I have a `button` and I added it's target like this

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myFunction), for: .touchUpInside)

func myFunction() {
    print("Hello world")
}
```

But in this case, myFunction just print a string "Hello world".
I don't want to make a lot of function which just do one work like that.

So I want to know if there have any way to perform a block of code in `#selector`

I want code like this :

```
button.addTarget(self, action: print("Hello World"), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: Look at [this workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36983811/335858) in particular, it should let you do what you are trying to achieve with a closure syntax.

Comment: Buttons don't work that way. A selector is the name of a method that the button calls when the user triggers the specified event (usually lifts his finger while inside the button.) You can't pass code into a button like that, but you CAN create a subclass of UIButton that takes a closure as a parameter and calls that closure when the specified event occurs.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight that answer looks like almost doing what he **doesn't** want to do.

Comment: Thank you guys a lot. I use closure like you guys said and now my code is a lot cleaner